# Joining characters not seperated by a particular character in lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

So I have an input of

```
6,10,47,3,6,9,54,7,9,0;3
```

and I put it into a list that appears as follows

```
['6', ',', '1', '0', ',', '4', '7', ',', '3', ',', '6', ',', '9', ',', '5', '4', ',', '7', ',', '9', ',', '0', ';', '3']
```

Now as you see double digit numbers are now seperate. I understand that if I use    .split(',') I could have split everything perfectly from the start, but I was wondering if it is possible in this state to join the numbers that are meant to be together (the ones not seperated by a "," character) and keep them in the same place in the list. ie 1,0 are replaced by 10 in the list:

```
['6', ',', '10', ',',...]
```

I tried

```py
def join_nums(v):
    for id2, char in enumerate(v):
        if id2 == len(v) - 1:
            return v
        elif isinstance(v[id2 + 1], int):
            v[id2:id2 + 1] = ["".join(v[id2:id2 + 1])]
```

it runs but doesn't do anything (not even sure if close because I haven't quite got my head around enumerating lists yet!)
Can anyone push me in the right direction. Thank you.

EDIT: The ";" is not a typo. I reason I chose to not split from the start was because I needed the ","s later else I would have to rewrite a few functions. I should of specified this from the beginning, sorry.

Comment: Is there any significance to the `;` instead of `,` before the last number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can still operate the original string (or you can join the list you've got back to a string), you can use `re.findall()` in this case. This would output the numbers and the delimiters in the same list in order:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"\d+|[,;]", s)
['6', ',', '10', ',', '47', ',', '3', ',', '6', ',', '9', ',', '54', ',', '7', ',', '9', ',', '0', ';', '3']
```

Here `\d+|[,;]` would match one or more digits (`\d+`) or a single comma, or a single semi-colon.

Comment: This operates on the original string, not the list he's trying to combine, right?

Comment: @Barmar good point, yes, let's see if it would fit the OP's use case. Thanks.

Comment: He says in the question that he could have used `split()` from the start to get what he wants. So it seems like he's really looking for a way to merge elements in the list, not start from the string again.

Comment: Sorry i should have specified that I needed to keep the commas until a later point, splitting by commas from the beginning - although would fix one problem - would cause problems elsewhere. Converting to a string and back to a list works great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that uses itertools:

```
lst = ['6', ',', '1', '0', ',', '4', '7', ',', '3', ',', '6', ',', '9', ',', '5', '4', ',', '7', ',', '9', ',', '0', ';', '3']
import itertools
groups = itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x.isdigit())
result = []
for is_int, vals in groups:
    if is_int:
        result.append(''.join(vals))
    else:
        result.extend(vals)

print(result)  # ['6', ',', '10', ',', '47', ',', '3', ',', '6', ',', '9', ',', '54', ',', '7', ',', '9', ',', '0', ';', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `for` loop:

```
x = ['6', ',', '1', '0', ',', '4', '7', ',', '3', ',', '6', ',', '9', ',', '5', '4', ',', '7', ',', '9', ',', '0', ';', '3']
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
     if i < len(x)-1:
             if x[i+1] in ',;':
                     y.append(int(x[i]));
             else:
                     if x[i] not in ',;':
                             y.append(int(x[i]+x[i+1]))
     else:
             y.append(int(x[i]))

print y #[6, 10, 0, 47, 7, 3, 6, 9, 54, 4, 7, 9, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
corrected = ''.join(wrongly_split).split(',')
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I didn't have the audacity to suggest it. :)

Comment: Yeah, but this would not result into `,` and `;` being in the output list.

Comment: But that doesn't get the `;` . . . although, I'm not sure what OP wanted with that anyway. . .

Comment: Let's see what OP wants to do to `;`, or maybe it's just a typo... (@alecxe @mgilson I guess it's a typo; otherwise OP wouldn't have said that s/he could have split on `,`) Anyway the message is, maybe it's not too late to re-start from "the start" :)